# Android Studio Device Manager Okta Auth

Tags: android, android-studio, okta

I am developing an application that authenticates via Okta. I'm trying to test locally using Android Studio's Virtual Device Manager, but I'm running into issues.  I'm not sure if it is proxy related (my proxy settings are defined in Android Studio's Manual proxy configuration), but the Intent is failing to open the browser saying it cannot reach source. FYI. I'm able to build using the proxy settings.

thanks in advance for any guidance